# How can I filter out duplicated identities for their earliest timestamp value, then filter for identities that appear in two seprate lists?

Tags: sql, filter

So I have the following query that tells me when some securities have come alive (i.e. when `val=True`):

```
select * from sval where fid = 4044 and val = 'True';
```

The output of the above looks something like:

```
id      fid         timestamp       val 
 1      4044        2019-01-22      True
 2      4044        2020-02-22      True 
 3      4044        2023-02-02      True 
 1      4044        2020-05-28      True
 4      4044        2023-05-03      True
 ....
```

For every security it may come alive, die, then come alive again, so each `id` could have more than one entry. I would like to somehow filter for the earliest alive entry, i.e. the earliest time for each security where `val = True`. Any ideas how to do this?

Then the following query will simply produce a list of unique identities:

```
select distinct(id) from ival where fid = 3994 and val=0
```

I would then like to filter for all the `id`s that appear in both lists - is there a way to do this?

Comment: which databse system are you using, if it supports row_:number use it

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure, sample input data, and the expected output corresponding to that data

Comment: I am using postgres SQL, Dbeaver

Comment: @NicoHaase what do you mean by table structure? The sample input is as per above? - not quite sure what else to share

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: Like more information on the `ival` table?

Comment: `both lists` ... what are the two lists?

Comment: Ahh, both lists consist of just the identities; the identities that I get from the output of the above two queries.
The first query above produces more than just identities, it produces the `fid`, `timestamp` and `val` too.

As per my first question above, I would like to filter the first list of identities to be distrinct and hold the identities of the earliest `timestamp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your RDBMS is PostgreSQL then use `distinct on` to extract the earliest occurrence of each `id` with `val = 'True'` from table `sval`.

```sql
select distinct on (id) * 
from sval 
where val = 'True' -- just WHERE val (if it's boolean)
order by id, "timestamp";
```

To extract only `id`s that appear in `ival` you can then shape this query as a CTE and inner join it with `ival` using column `id`.

```sql
with t as
(
 select distinct on (id) id 
 from sval 
 where val = 'True' -- just WHERE val (if it's boolean)
 order by id, "timestamp"
)
select distinct t.id from t inner join ival using (id)
where where ival.fid = 3994 and ival.val=0;
```

Comment: thank you! 

For your second query, how can I replace 
`select t.id from t inner join ival using (id);` with 
`select distinct(id) from ival where fid = 3994 and val=0;`?

Comment: Where `select distinct(id) from ival where fid = 3994 and val=0;` simply returns a bunch of identities.

Comment: @ifrj I am not sure that I understand where `fid = 3994` is coming from since you asked for "the earliest time for _each_ security". Anyway you can simply _append_ the `where` clause to the end of the second query.

Comment: I am asking two questions; the first one is to get "the earliest time for each security", and your suggested query to do this works completely fine!

Comment: My comment was for the second question I am asking (to find the intersection of the two identity lists). See my second query in my question, it is: `select distinct(id) from ival where fid = 3994 and val=0`. I am trying to figure out how to incorporate this into your suggested answer to my second quetion.

Comment: @ifrj The second query in the answer does filter for all the ids that appear in both lists (earliest alive from `sval` and present in `ival`). You can `distinct` the list and add `where fid = 3994 and ival.val=0`.

Comment: How can I do it? Could you revise the answer? 

Do you mean replace `using (id)` with `using(distinct(id)) where fid=3994 and ival.val=0`?

Comment: @ifrj Check it out

Comment: Amazing, the query went through thank you. 

Is there a way to get a count of the number of rows it produces? As it will be in the millions in my case.

Comment: @ifrj Sure. Wrap the whole query into a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) `the_cte` and then `select count(*) from the_cte`;

Answer (score 0):

select (columns) from sval where fid = 4044 and val = 'True' order by timestamp limit 1; -- Postgresql

or

select (columns) from sval where fid = 4044 and val = 'True' and rownum = 1 order by timestamp; -- Oracle

Comment: This only returns 1 row of data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).